# How to Create Single template for custom post

Tags: custom-post-types

I create a custom post type add following code in theme's `functions.php`

```
function  cptarchivePost_init() {
    $args = array(
      'label' => 'Archive Post',
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'cpt_archive_post'),
        'query_var' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-video-alt',
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'editor',
            'excerpt',
            'trackbacks',
            'custom-fields',
            'comments',
            'revisions',
            'thumbnail',
            'author',
            'page-attributes',)
        );
    register_post_type( 'cpt_archive_post', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'cptarchivePost_init' );

add_action( 'init', 'create_cpt_archive_category', 0 );
function create_cpt_archive_category() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'cpt_archive_category',
        'cpt_archive_post',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => 'Category',
                'add_new_item' => 'Add Category',
                'new_item_name' => "New Category"
            ),
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_tagcloud' => false,
            'hierarchical' => true
        )
    );
}
```

and create a file/template in theme with name `single-cpt_archive_post.php` but still the post using index.php template

can anyone help how can I create single template for custom post

Comment: What of 123 steps have you been followed? Disable? Change?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use (page) templates for custom post types, see [this link](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/#creating-custom-page-templates-for-global-use).

Just add this to you template file:

```
Template Post Type: your-post-type
```